# A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development

Tags: cross-domain

Getting this error while accessing "react-google-maps" package for google routing,

```
const MyMapComponent = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
)(props => {
    const [styles, setStyles] = useState({ currentStyle: "AubergineWithoutMarker" });
```

Getting this error while accessing "react-google-maps" package for google routing and tried to fix CORS issue even without network but still the issue is happening.